# Installation to internal Hard drive

Tags: system-installation

Downloaded and wrote Ubuntu 14.04 to a 16GB USB Flash drive.
This is bootable  but not persistent.

Question : How to Install  Ubuntu to the machine's hard drive (the actual Hard disk  drive  of the machine) to  have a persistent  install  where the machine boots directly from the Hard disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). Installing from a USB flash drive is very similar to installing via DVD, so it should help. I'm assuming you know how to boot into the USB flash drive, so the above instructions should guide you through the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

The Ubuntu installation guides are well written. If you have any other issues, you can post to here. The links should explain all, however.
(Note: A little Googling can go a long way, and probably the first place to check is the Ubuntu installation website!)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble figuring this out earlier today but, I got it. This is how I did it:

- Plug the flash drive into an empty USB port
- Reboot and open you BIOS editor
- Set the BIOS to boot to the Flash Drive
- Once the installer starts click the "change" button on the middle left side
- Create a partition for Ubuntu and choose the file system you want to use
- Create a partition for the swap area
- Click "Continue" and let the install finish
- Reboot to the BIOS editor again and set the hard drive to the priority you want and either disable the flash drive from booting or put it after the HDD in priority
- Remove the Flash Drive (Ubuntu wouldn't boot with it in the USB Port for me)
- Save and Exit the Bios

And you're off to the races. Good luck :)